# Failed to parse using HTML on ICS

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to parse a website to obtain news information. It works well on previous version of Android but it doesn't work on ICS. Here's the piece of code that worked before:

```
public NewsParsing(){

    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.curtin.edu.my/campusnews/index.htm");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (doc != null)
    {
        newsArray = new ArrayList<NewsStructure>();
        Element latestNews = doc.select("div[id=post-]").first();

        Iterator<Element> newsTable = latestNews.select("div[id=post-6400]").iterator();

        while (newsTable.hasNext())
        {
            newsContent         = new NewsStructure();
            Element currIte     = newsTable.next();
            Element hElement    = currIte.getElementsByTag("h2").first();
            String newsTitle    = hElement.select("a").first().text().toString();
            String newsLink     = hElement.select("a").first().attr("href").toString();
            Element sElement    = currIte.getElementsByTag("div").first();
            String newsSnippet  = sElement.select("p").first().text().toString();
            Element dElement    = currIte.getElementsByTag("p").last();
            String newsDate     = dElement.text().toString();
            newsContent.setTitle(newsTitle);
            newsContent.setLink(newsLink);
            newsContent.setSnippet(newsSnippet);
            newsContent.setDate(newsDate);
            newsArray.add(newsContent);
        }

    }
}
```

The logcat:

```
07-13 03:18:07.830: W/dalvikvm(1595): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.csmict.csm/my.csmict.csm.CurtinNewsMain}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:404)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:391)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:157)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:146)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at my.csmict.csm.NewsParsing.<init>(NewsParsing.java:22)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at my.csmict.csm.CurtinNewsMain.onCreate(CurtinNewsMain.java:33)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-13 03:18:07.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Please advice. I'm using Jsoup 1.6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform network connections on a separate thread, or else a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` will be thrown. You can offload the work to a separate thread using an `AsyncTask`. Read my blog post on the subject here:

### [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Comment: thanks a million! tried implementing asynctask on the class and it worked :D

Comment: Always use `AsyncTask` (or `Thread`, etc.) to perform network accesses, disk reads/writes, database queries, etc. :)